# How to fix angular-translate FOUC issues while using translatePartialLoader?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I've been experiencing FOUC (flash of untranslated content) issues while using angular-translate. This is my setup:

```
.config(function ($translateProvider, defaultI18n) {
    $translateProvider
        .useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize')
        .translations('en-GB', defaultI18n.en)
        .useCookieStorage()
        .useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
            urlTemplate: '/{part}/{lang}.json'
        })
        .preferredLanguage('en-GB')
        .fallbackLanguage('en-GB');
})
.run(function ($rootScope, $translate) {
    $rootScope.$on('$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function () {
        $translate.refresh();
});
```

Since I'm using `$translatePartialLoader` in each controller view I have:

```
.controller('SomeController', function ($translatePartialLoader) {
    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('path-to-some-view-i18n');
})
```

If I remove `$translate.refresh()` FOUC goes away, but the text isn't updated with the new locale. Not sure if having text in my HTML files maybe causing a conflict here.

**How can I remove FOUC completely but still keeping the app translating correctly?**

**Should I remove all text from my HTML files?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the logic a bit and the FOUC issues seem to disappear. Instead of executing `$translatePartialLoader.addPart('path-to-some-view-i18n');` in each controller, I defined for each state the respective i18n route(s) like this:

```
.state('state1', {
    url: '/state1',
    templateUrl: 'path-to-some-view',
    data: {
        i18n: ['path-to-some-view-i18n']
    }
})
```

And then, when the event `$stateChangeStart` is triggered:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if(toState.data.i18n) {
            angular.forEach(toState.data.i18n, function (value) {
                $translatePartialLoader.addPart(value);
            });
        }
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function () {
        $translate.refresh();
    });
});
```

Comment: can you suggest a strategy to use this approach with states which are loaded in home page automatically

Comment: Also I came across a problem when tried to load data in dropdowns, it's sometimes slow, or never gets populated without any errors

Comment: Maybe `translate-cloak` directive can be useful in your case. For further reading: [here](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.directive:translateCloak) and [here](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading#asynchronous-loading_fouc---flash-of-untranslated-content).

Comment: Also please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247083/how-to-load-angular-translate-before-any-ui-is-displayed-with-ui-router-resolve                for resolving FOUC issue.